# How to find whether particular email id is a valid id or not before sign in that email service provider?

Tags: vb.net, email, user-interface

I am creating a windows form where i get inputs for mail id,password,service provider name from the user...i want to validate whether the user entered email id is valid for the service provider entered in that form and send a file to google drive?. How to do it?. If i search i found [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs)  code but i don't understand it. or  any feasible solution is there?

Comment: @downvoter have guts? then specify the reason for downvote

Comment: I don't think this will be possible to do automatically. You could build up your own database of providers to email address domain list but this would be time consuming and you can guarantee that you won't have thought of everyone. Why do you need to do this? If they enter an invalid provider/email combination it will just fail anyway won't it? (ps I'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is verify that the email address exists for that server, here is a description of the protocol:

http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/

If you need to know if it is a valid Google Drive account, then that is a separate problem.